# How to ignore an insert of already exisiting unique value?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table `keywords(keyid, keyword)`, with `keyid` being the `primary key` and `keyword` being `varchar` and `unique`.

How can I insert non-existing values and ignore the values that already exist in the table without getting an error?

For example I insert `a, b, c, d`. Then I insert `c, d, e, f`. It should ignore c and d, and insert e and f.

Comment: Via `INSERT IGNORE INTO...` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html or take different action via `ON DUPLICATE KEY...`

Comment: possible duplicate of ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [`ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), e.g.

```
INSERT INTO keywords (keyid, keyword) 
     VALUES (100, 'a keyword') 
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE keyid = keyid;
```

This way the alternative `UPDATE` is executed, if `keyid` already exists.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` function. Documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Example

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```